# fade out div when mouse is still

Tags: jquery

I've made a div show on mousemove. now I need it to fade out when mouse is not moving. I've tried this, but the problem is that when the div is in "fadeout-mood", it don't show again when I move the mouse.

is there someone who can help me with this?

```
$("#main_center").mousemove(function(){
    $("#menylist").show("");
    $("#menylist").fadeOut(5000);
```

the actual page is here: http://www.martinsorensson.com/porrmyr/index.php

Kindly 
Martin

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#main_center").mousemove(function(){
    $("#menylist").stop().show().css('opacity',1).animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing brackets, try this out:

```
$("#main_center").mousemove(function(){ 
    $("#menylist").show("");
}); 
$("#menylist").fadeOut(5000);
```

or you may try this:

```
$("#main_center").mousemove(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for what you want to do, you must also stop the fading animation on mouse motion:

```
$('#main_center').mousemove( function(e) {
    $('#menylist').stop().show();
    $('#menylist').fadeOut(5000);
});
```

Note the `stop()` call. Is this what you were looking for?

EDIT: David's solution is better than mine, because `fadeOut()` sets `display` to `none`, which probably is not what you want.